# distance beetween Checkbox and Text

Tags: apache-flex

how to increase the distance between the text and the check box in flex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the gap by using the **horizontalGap** property (style)

```
<mx:CheckBox id="chk" label="Hello" horizontalGap="50" />
```

or

> chk.setStyle("horizontalGap", 50);

Answer (score 1):

You can use textIndent Property:

```
 <mx:CheckBox label="some text" textIndent="5"/>
```